# Server configuration is open, but client is denied access

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Apache/2.4.29
```

I have the following in my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myapp.conf (sym links to sites-avaiable):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myserver.com

   DocumentRoot /home/myapp/public

   PassengerRuby /path-to-ruby

   <Directory /home/myapp/public>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But, when I try to access myserver.com, I get:

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at myserver.com Port 80
```

Here's what's in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Wed Sep 11 12:00:14.600311 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 1961:tid 139643440449280] [client xxxxxxx] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/myapp/public/
```

When I do ls -l /home/myapp, I get:

```
drwxrwxr-x   4 myapp myapp   4096 Sep 11 10:39 public
```

Any ideas?

Comment: uncomment `#Require all granted`

Comment: This worked. I misinterpreted the directions, the Apache server is > 2.4, so the line should have been uncommented